# Moving all zeros to the end of the list while leaving False alone

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I have a list: `[9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9,False]` and I  want to move all zeros to the end.

I know I can use:

```
sorted([9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9], key=lambda x: x == 0)
```

but it will move `False` to the end of the list as well, which is not what I want.

How do I move only zeroes but leave `False` values at their original places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `False == 0` is True (indeed, the success of our `sorted` `key` function depends on this), if you wish to treat `False` as non-zero, then you'll need to add that as another condition:

```
sorted([9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9,False], 
       key=lambda x: (x == 0) and x is not False)
```

yields

```
[9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, False, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```