# Move zeros to the end of a list while leaving False alone

Tags: python, list

I have some code that should find the position of any `0` items in a list and move it to the back whilst preserving the order of the other elements.

```
def test2(array):
    try:
        for n in range(len(array)):
            array.append(array.pop(array.index(0)))
        return array
    except ValueError:
        return array
```

This code works fine for any list apart from one with `False` in. I think this is because the `.index(0)`: will also return the position of any False in the list. Any way to get around this?

For example if `array = [0,1,None,2,False,1,0]` then the output should be `[1,None,2,False,1,0,0]`

With that same input my code produces: `[1, None, 2, 1, False, 0, 0]`

Comment: `0 == False`. Booleans do that in Python.

Comment: @user2357112 So is there a different way I can do this then?

Comment: You just need to handle the `0 == False` is `True` in Python, that is main reason you are not able to get correct ans. 

More details please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving all zeros to the end of the list while leaving False alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187105/moving-all-zeros-to-the-end-of-the-list-while-leaving-false-alone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` in python, so searching for the first index of `0` will return the index of `False`, if it is in the list before a `0` because `False == 0`.

What you can do is check whether a list element is an instance of `int`, and at the same time, *not* an instance of `bool`. This way, you avoid matching other false values (like empty containers and `None`).

```
def is_zero(v):
    # return is instance(v, int) and v is not False and not v
    # return isinstance(v, int) and not isinstance(v, bool) and not v
    return type(v) in (int, float) and not v
```

You can then iterate over `lst` in reverse and update in-place.

```
lst = [1, 0, None, False, 0, 3, True] # For example.

for i in reversed(range(len(lst))):
    if is_zero(lst[i]):
        lst.append(lst.pop(i))

print(lst)
# [1, None, False, 3, True, 0, 0]
```

This is amortised linear time complexity, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Just curious, instead of checking `isinstance`, is it safe in python to simply check `v is not False`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I would be _very_ careful of using `is` for anything besides reference checks.

Comment: I guess that's what I was asking: does python make any guarantees here. Seems like the answer is no. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I believe True and False values are interned (cached), so with cpython the reference _should_ be the same... but it is an implementation detail and in general you should not rely on it. :-)

Comment: @coldspeed Just curious, what does the `and not v` do?

Comment: @HarryDay 0 is falsey, so not 0 evaluates to True. It's cleaner than v == 0 IMO, because it's more "pythonic", so to speak.

Comment: Python does guarantee that `True` and `False` are the *only* instances of `bool`, so it is safe to use them in `is` checks. This also applies to `None`, `NotImplemented`, and `Ellipsis`.

Comment: @coldspeed how could I expand this code to also change `0.0` to `0` and move it to the back also?

Comment: @HarryDay you can pass a tuples of types as the second argument to isinstance. So, isinstance(v, (int, float)), see if you can figure it out from there!

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks! I got there anyway before I read your hint ;)

Answer (score 2):

If creating another list is of no concern, you can use list-comprehensions:

```
def test2(array):
    la = len(array)
    return ([x for x in array if not isinstance(x,int) or x]+[0]*la)[:la]
```

The first part filters out any 0 integerbut lets any non-int pass. The second part adds (too many) zeros and trims the result back down to the original lenght.

**Caveat:** This will create up to twice the original list-length in data - so not good for "big" lists or lists with few 0.

Usage:

```
k = [1,2,3,0,4,5,False,92,-3,0,1,0,0,True,[],None,True]
print(k)
print(test2(k))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, False, 92, -3, 0, 1, 0, 0, True, [], None, True]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 92, -3, 1, True, True, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Doku:

- (related) [Truth-testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) - there are other values that are "False" as well.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @coldspeed's solution:

```
array = [0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0]
nonzero = [x for x in array if x or x is None or isinstance(x,bool)]
nonzero + [0] * (len(array) - len(nonzero))
# [1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper with a custom `__eq__`:

```
class Typed:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.val)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Typed):
            other = other.val
        return type(self.val) is type(other) and self.val == other
```

Then replace `array.index(0)` with `array.index(Typed(0))` - you don't need to use this within the array itself.

Extending this to containers (so that `(0, 1)` and `(False, True)` won't be equal) is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as concise as this can be. Thanks for the help everyone

```
l = [i for i in array if isinstance(i, bool) or i!=0]
return l+[0]*(len(array)-len(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python [guarantees](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) `True` and `False` are the only instances of `bool`, so you can use `is` to distinguish `False` from `0`.

```
z = []
return [e for e in array if e is False or e != 0 or z.append(e)] + z
```

This will preserve the order of the various non-`False` zeros (`0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`),  that may be in the list.