# How can i move just Zero to the end of my list and not False in python

Tags: python

```
def move_zeros(array):
    for element in array:
        if element == 0 and type(element) is not bool:
            array.append(array.pop(array.index(element)))
    return array

print(move_zeros([False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]))
```

My result is `[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', False, 0, 0]`
 I don't want False to move, my program sees False as 0.

Comment: What the answers neglect to tell you is that your conditional logic is correct. You're being tripped up by `array.index(element)` which matches `False` even if `element` is `0`. If you were to build a new list rather than mutating your original one your code would work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving all zeros to the end of the list while leaving False alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187105/moving-all-zeros-to-the-end-of-the-list-while-leaving-false-alone)

Answer (score 4):

This is coming about because you're operating on the list while looping over it, as well as the issue that you've correctly identified, that `False == 0` and `0 == 0` both are `True` in Python. One way to deal with this is the following, using `is` instead of `==` to check equality to `0`:

```
def move_zeros(a):
    return [x for x in a if x is not 0] + [x for x in a if x is 0]

print(move_zeros([False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]))
```

Output:

```
[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```

Note that the use of `is` to compare integers is not safe in general because integers outside of the range (-5, 256) have different ids from each other ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)). In our case however, we are just using `0`, so the solution above is safe.

Comment: Where does Python guarantee that there's only one `0` object? For example, it doesn't work with 666. After `a = [666]`, `[x for x in a if x is 666]` gives me `[]` because the `666` object in the list comprehension is a different `666` object than the one in the list.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) - `is` works in this case because `0` is in the range `(-5, 256)`. This won't work if we change the value to `666`, but then `666 == False` isn't `True`, so we don't have the problem that the OP is facing.

Comment: @CDJB that's more than just an aside, I would suggest adding that information (and a safe alternative) to your answer. I also don't know how non-CPython implementations handle small ints.

Comment: @CDJB I don't see a guarantee there. Only the statement that "The current implementation" (of CPython) does that. That's not safe.

Comment: Absolutely **not** a correct solution. You should **never** rely on implementation details like this, this is not a guarantee. It could change in a different version of Python, heck, not even a different micro-level could change this. Totally wrong. This solution **is not safe**.

Comment: Just noticed the paragraph right before the [section of the language reference @StefanPochmann cited](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) states that "for immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value" and gives an example as well: "after `a = 1; b = 1`, `a` and `b` may or may not refer to the same object with the value one, depending on the implementation". This doubles down on the fact, that identity comparison to small ints is unsafe.

Comment: It is possible in CPython also to have low integers in different memory locations.  See [*How to create the int 1 at two different memory locations?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21456318/674039) for an example. The intern is there for a performance boost, nothing more - must not be relied on in logic.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution and showing that your check is actually ok:

```
>>> sorted(array, key=lambda x: x == 0 and type(x) is not bool)
[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```

Or compare with the `False` singleton:

```
>>> sorted(array, key=lambda x: x == 0 and x is not False)
[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```

Or if you're feeling playful, chained comparisons:

```
>>> sorted(array, key=lambda x: 0 == x is not False)
[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```

Comment: Please whats the function of the sorted() used in this code ?

Comment: @AchebePeter I'm sorting the elements by whether they're zero or not.

Answer (score 1):

This does the inplace shuffling of "zero" to the end, costing O(1) space and O(n) time complexity.

```
def move_zeroes_to_end(nums):
    n = len(nums)
    non_zero = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if nums[i] != 0 or type(nums[i])==bool:
            nums[non_zero],nums[i] = nums[i],nums[non_zero]
            non_zero +=1
    return nums


l=[False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]

print(move_zeroes_to_end(l)) #Output:[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```

Comment: This changes the order of different zeroes, though. For example `[0, 0.0, 1]` becomes `[1, 0.0, 0]`. But maybe that's ok.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that case, I guess we might require two pass through the array for that ?

Comment: Can you do it with two passes? Still with O(1) and O(n)? I don't know an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `pop()`+`append()`, just with a "free counting" loop, which is mainly a `while`:

```
def move_zeros(a):
  l=len(a)
  i=0
  while i<l:
    if a[i] is 0:
      a.append(a.pop(i))
      l=l-1
    else:
      i=i+1
  return a

print(move_zeros([False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]))
```

Produces the output maintaining the order as:

> ```
> [False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation, using counter with loop:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    result, count = [], 0
    for i in array:
        if i == 0 and type(i) == int: count+= 1
        else: result.append(i)
    return result + [0]*count

print(move_zeros([False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]))
```

**Output**

```
[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save False as a String. Then it is not seen as 0.
change your code to:

```
print(move_zeros(["False",1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
type(element) is not bool
```

to:

```
not element == False and not element == True
```

It's longer, but it fixes your problem

Comment: The original snippet is correct, yours is wrong. The problem is elsewhere.